# TOR asking for donations?

Tags: configuration, security

I downloaded new TOR and got an ad on the top of the browser stating "Please support TOR   DONATE" with a pic of Cory Doctorow on the top of the page. I never saw TOR advertise before. Is this the real TOR or am I compromised?

Comment: you can or better should (especially if you are unsure) [verify the signatures for your downloaded packages](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest [release info](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-505-released) says:

> Tor Browser 5.0.5 comes with a banner supporting our donations
>   campaign. The banner is visible on the about:tor page and features
>   either Roger    Dingledine, Laura Poitras or Cory Doctorow which is
>   chosen randomly.

Comment: It is also noteworthy that the banner only appears 10 times in total. I briefly thought my browser was owned until I read gk's comment in the [tor browser 5.0.6 release blog post](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-506-released). `It is only shown 10 times in total. If you want to see it again just set extensions.torbutton.donation_banner.shown_count to a value smaller than 10. :)`